# Chaining groupby and pluck

Tags: underscore.js

```
data =[
{
    "origin": "Mumbai",
    "destination": "Chennai"
},
{
    "origin": "Mumbai",
    "destination": "Delhi",
},
{
    "origin": "Pune",
    "destination": "Brahmapur",
},]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {"Mumbai" : ["Chennai","Delhi"]},
  {"Pune" : ["Brahmapur"]}
]
```

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
var list = _.pluck(data, 'destination'); // it gives the array of destinations
var gList = _.groupBy(data, 'origin'); // it gives me json which are grouped by the origin key.
```

I tried to below to combine **pluck** and **groupby** that would be give me just the array of destinations for particular origin key but obviously its not working.

```
var gpList = _.groupBy(_.pluck(data, 'parname'), 'category');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there with those choice of functions.

The first thing to do is to [**groupBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) origin. This will return an object that looks like this:

```
{
    Mumbai: [ { origin: 'Mumbai', destination: 'Chennai' },
              { origin: 'Mumbai', destination: 'Delhi' } ],

    Pune: [ { origin: 'Pune', destination: 'Brahmapur' } ]
}
```

Then use [**mapObject**](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject) to [**pluck**](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) the destination:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('origin')
    .mapObject(group => _.pluck(group, 'destination'))
    .value()
```